# I am not able to compile my code with mpicc

Tags: path, compiler-errors, compilation, permissions

I am using the following script to compile my code. I had previously installed mpich2 in the following folder: /user/kumarvis/u2/mpich2-install. However the directory is no more accessible to me. So I installed mpich2 in a different directory as indicated by PATH

```
module load intel-mpi/4.0
PATH=/projects/academic/advisor/mpich2-install/bin:$PATH
export PATH
clear
make veryclean
rm -rf twoBody2015TenComponentsWithMerge.exe twoBody2015TenComponentsWithMerge.o
mpicc -c -I ../include -O -o twoBody2015TenComponentsWithMerge.o twoBody2015TenComponentsWithMerge.c
```

However, when I compile my code using this script, I get the following error:
[image]

i.e. it is using the old directory which is no more accessible to me. I don't know why it is using old directory to access mpich2 even though it is not included in PATH.

Comment: To investigate the issue, could you try to add commands like `which mpicc` and `echo $PATH` just before the call to `mpicc`? Some command in the makefile might prepend the directory `/user/..../u2/...` to the PATH: could you try to comment `make veryclean`?

Comment: I found my mistake. In the mpicc file, the prefix was set to the old directory. When I modified it, the code was able to compile.